# while Integrating nodejs -mysql module file into app.use getting an error file notfound error404

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I created a nodejs-mysql file .
when i give listen(8084) port number and test on browser it displays data .
when i integrate into main folder app.use('/', salonsce_fournisseur) which use default 3000 port and without 8084 number .
    it is showing an error 404 file not found.
    some body please explain to me where i am doing mistake.
here is the code

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var router = express.Router();
    var http = require('http');
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var url = require('url');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            database: 'test'
        });

    var fournisseurJoinsQuery = 'SELECT     * FROM  `salonsce_fournisseurs`;
    console.log('MySQL Connection details  '+connection);
    http.createServer(function (req, res) 
    { 
            var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
        var query1 = url_parts.query;
        console.lop('kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk')
        console.log(query1);
        console.log('Creating the http server');
        connection.query(fournisseurJoinsQuery , function(err, rows, fields)
        {   

            console.log('Connection result error '+err);
            console.log('no of records is '+rows.length);
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            res.end(JSON.stringify({"success":1,"count":rows.length,"results":rows}));
            res.end();
        }); 

    });
```

module.exports = router;

```
my app.js code is:


var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//var mysql = require('mysql');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var files = require('./routes/files');

var salonsce_photos = require('./routes/salonsce.photos');
var salonsce_fournisseur = require('./routes/salonsce.fournisseur');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/salonsce.photos', salonsce_photos);
app.use('/salonsce.fournisseur', salonsce_fournisseur);
```

});

```
module.exports = app;
```

if i type on url : localhost:3000/salonsce.fournisseur it should display the data.
Thanks in advance.